# GridView does not fill screen

Tags: android-layout

I have a "grid_test.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutGrid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am including this in another layout with header and footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/commonlayout" >


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_settings"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView android:id="@+id/svdata"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llheader" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/llfooter" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lldata"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgound_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <include layout="@layout/grid_test" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption1"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption2"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption3"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the included GridView layout does not fill the screen between header and footer.

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found it. Removing the ScrollView, makes it work as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/commonlayout" >


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_settings"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lldata"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgound_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llheader" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/llfooter" 
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <include layout="@layout/grid_test" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption1"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption2"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOption3"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```